# SQLite trigger expr for deleting parent when no children

Tags: triggers, sqlite, conditional-statements

There is a classic parent/child set of table in a SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE ImageGallery (
    ImageGalleryId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
    Name VARCHAR(80) UNIQUE NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE Image (
    ImageId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , 
    ImageGalleryId INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    Filename VARCHAR(260) NOT NULL, 
    FullPath VARCHAR(260) NOT NULL 
    );
```

There needs to be an trigger that fires after an Image is deleted that will delete the ImageGallery if there are no more Images in that gallery, basically something like this:

```
if ((select count(*) from Image where ImageGalleryId = old.imageGalleryId) == 0) then
begin
  delete from ImageGallery where ImageGalleryId = old.imageGalleryId
end
```

What exactly does that look like in the SQLite dialect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite has no IF statement.

However, triggers have a [WHEN clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER xxx
AFTER DELETE ON Image
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Image WHERE ImageGalleryId = OLD.ImageGalleryId) = 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ImageGallery WHERE ImageGalleryId = OLD.ImageGalleryId;
END;
```